# Limitar cantidad de registros y ordenarlos

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subconsultas

Tengo dos tablas una de **clientes** y una de **ventas** donde debo seleccionar los 30 ÚLTIMOS registros añadidos a la tabla **ventas**, mostrar la informacion de los clientes que realizaron esas transacciones y ordenarlos de manera ascendente respecto al id de **ventas**.
los campos de ambas tablas son:

**clientes**

```
id , nombre, apellido_paterno,apellido_materno, rut, dv
```

**ventas**

```
id, cliente_id, fecha
```

tengo la siguiente consulta que me devuelve la informacion de los clientes que han sido registrados en la tabla ventas, pero me falta que solo seleccione las ultimas 30 ventas realizadas y ordenarlas por su id.

```
 select nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,rut,dv,venta.id,venta.fecha
 from cliente inner join venta on cliente.id = venta.cliente_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar al final de tu consulta SQL lo siguiente

```
SELECT nombre,apellido_paterno,apellido_materno,rut,dv,
       venta.id,venta.fecha
FROM cliente INNER JOIN venta ON cliente.id = venta.cliente_id 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30;
```

Donde:

> 1. `ORDER BY` indica que ordenaremos el `dataset` de resultados por la columna `id`, junto con `DESC`
> 2. `LIMIT` 30 indica que junto con `DESC` de la condición anterior solo se limite a tomar los 30 registros que queden en ese rango

Tu coloca el nombre de la columna id que sea adecuado para la tabla ventas

Comment: funciono perfecto gracias!, aunque estoy seguro que lo había probado de una forma similar y me lanzaba errores, pero bueno esto a ido bien.

Comment: que bueno te sirvió, siempre que tengas dudas puedes publicarlas y en la medida de lo posible te apoyaremos saludos